# Cannot install ImportExcel Powershell module

Tags: excel, powershell, module, installation

First, I would like to say that I'm a total beginner, so please try not to use to complexe words. I use Powershell V5 and I need to run the following line :

```
Install-Module ImportExcel -scope CurrentUser
```

But an error message appears

> Install-Module : Le terme «Install-Module» n'est pas reconnu comme nom
>   d'applet de commande, fonction, fichier de script ou  programme
>   exécutable. Vérifiez l'orthographe du nom, ou si un chemin d'accès
>   existe, vérifiez que le chemin d'accès est  correct et réessayez.

en:

> The term 'Install-Module' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
>   function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
>   name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and 
>   try again.

I have the Powershell version 5.0 :

> PSVersion                      5.0.10586.117
>   PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
>   BuildVersion                   10.0.10586.117
>   CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.36366
>   WSManStackVersion              3.0
>   PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
>   SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1

Comment: whats your powershell version?

Comment: Install-Module is part of the [PowerShellGet Module](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dn835097.aspx) The PowerShellGet module is installed with Windows PowerShell 5.0 and later releases of Windows PowerShell.

Comment: At minimum PS3.0 is required to install from [here](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PowerShellGet/1.1.2.0)

Comment: See your PowerShell version using `$PSVersionTable`.

Comment: Now, I have the Powershell version 5.0, but the problem still remains the same.

Comment: Does anybody know how to install a module?

Answer (score 5):

Very importantly run ***PowerShell elevated as administrator*** on your Windows machine and then run

```
Find-Module -Name PowerShellGet | Install-Module
Find-Module -Name ImportExcel | Install-Module
```

If you are prompted, just select "**Yes to all**" for each of those commands, and let both complete and once that's finished, try again.

> ### [ImportExcel  6.0.0](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/6.0.0)
>
> PowerShell module to import/export Excel spreadsheets, without Excel.
>
> [source](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/6.0.0)

Comment: This worked for me with Windows 10 and PowerShell 5.1 so I wanted to post as a more clear answer in case it helps others that stumble upon this post.

Answer (score 1):

I had to specify `-RequiredVersion 6.0.0` to get Install-Module -Name Import-Excel to not give me the "No match was found" error, on my Windows 11 Pro system, using Windows Powershell 5.1.22621.1778

```
Install-Module -Name ImportExcel -RequiredVersion 6.0.0
```